# ZFDataGrid support translator

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is it possible to translate a grid into multiple language (Chinese) in ZFDataGrid? if yes, please tell me how I can implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your translate object (Zend_Translator) to the grid:

```
$grid->setTranslator($translator);
```

After this it will try to translate your messageIds.